# DatumFactory is not an ImageIO SPI class

Tags: java, geotools

We are migrating our project to java 9 and I am getting this exception while using geotools:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.opengis.referencing.datum.DatumFactory is not an ImageIO SPI class
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed(ServiceRegistry.java:745)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:140)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.<init>(FactoryRegistry.java:155)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.<init>(FactoryRegistry.java:146)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.<init>(FactoryCreator.java:82)
```

My java version:

```
openjdk 9
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

I know there are some changes to support java 9 in [GeoTools 19.0](http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2018/03/geotools-190-released.html), but upgrading geotools to version 19.0 (and 20.x too!) doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check the `readme.html` file. I checked version 20.2 and it says:

> Warning: Java 9 is not yet supported

Comment: You're right. Also check [this](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6287?focusedCommentId=80316&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-80316)

Comment: Right, they're working on this. I downloaded Geotools in order to try to help you and started reading that readme file. :)

Comment: try 21.x and it should work with 9 though we have only tested with 11.

Comment: I can't find all needed geotools packages of same version in one place. They're spread across many repositories ... some of them not working. Is there any repository I can find all libs of same version together?